# if-statement that always is true

Tags: perl, if-statement

I would like to create and elsif statement in perl that always fullfil the condition. I would like that my code always goes into this 'elsif'

```
if (i==0){....}
elsif('what to write?') {...}
```

Should I write an constant value or perl has a keyword for that purpose?

Thanks

Comment: am as I missing something, why not just use an `else`?

Comment: either if or else, not both statements, right?

Comment: If you always want to do something then why create an if statement to begin with?

Comment: i think only infinite loops can become useful sometimes, why making if else if only one condition will always be true? In that case you dont need "if" or "else" anyway.

Comment: FYI, `if(CONSTANT)` and `elsif(CONSTANT)` are optimized, so it is largely irrelevant what you put there. However, a `do` or an `else` is easier to read.

Comment: I just need an If!! nothing else to write...

Comment: are you sure you need if at all? from your question it seems like you want some part of code that will always execute. if that is the case,you dont need if statement at all.

Comment: @BojanKovacevic i need it, there are some code lines that has to be execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an `if` condition that always passes, this should work:

```
if (1)
```

However, since you're at the end of an `if` block already, `else` will always pass.  There's no need to check a condition.

Answer (score 6):

Why not use `else` instead of `elsif`?

http://perlmeme.org/howtos/syntax/ifelsifelse.html#else

EDITED TO ADD:
If the desired behavior is to have some block of code **always** execute, whether or not the `if` statement executes, then just put the block of code below the `if`:

```
if (i == 0) { ... }

some_other_stuff_here_will_always_execute
```

Comment: Because if it has "entered" into IF it must also in elsif.

Comment: If the root "if" triggers (i.e. i is 0), no elsif or else will execute.

Comment: @JayDansand so how can I execute both?

Comment: @kmxillo By having two separate statements?

Comment: @kmxillo you will need to put all statements that need to execute for both the if and the elsif in both the if and elsif block otherwise only one of those will ever execute.

Comment: @kmxillo I've edited my answer to try to address your question.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
use 5.014;
if(0) {
        say "then";
}
elsif(1) {
        say "elsif";
}
else {
        say "else";
}
```